# Baum/Node - get descendants from more than one id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested-sets

I can get descendants from one ID like this:

```
    return $node = \App\Categories::where('id',41)
->first()
->getDescendants()->pluck('id');
```

I wonder if it's possible to get descendants of several ids with the same method?

I tried a "whereIn" like this but it doesn't work:

```
    return $node = \App\Categories::whereIn('id', array(41,94))
->get()
->getDescendants()
->pluck('id');
```

I believe `->get()` returns a Collection and I haven't succeeded in using a Baum/Node function on a Collection.
So I can only use them on single models?
So, should I loop through the ids and use `getDescendants()` on each id, is that the recommended way to do it?

Comment: Please post the `getDescendants()` method.

Comment: getDescendents is a baum/node method which is available on a class that extends Baum/Node https://github.com/etrepat/baum#accessing-the-ancestrydescendancy-chain

Comment: You'll probably have to collect them by looping over the categories.